# vsFTP, проблемы с заливкой файлов. пользователь anonymous

Tags: centos, ftp

Настроил ftp сервак.
ftp - vsFTPd;
OS - CentOS;
Iptables - отключены;
selinux - отключен;
НАТ не настроен, работаю в пределах локальной сети.

Задача: Нужно разграничить директории для локальных пользователей "privat", для анонимных "public". И локальным и анонимным доступ на скачивание + заливку.
С локальными пользователями проблем нет, все работает.

Под анонимным пользователем не дает заливать файлы. Скачивает норм.

вот лог

```html
Tue Apr  7 21:32:43 2015 [pid 2195] [ftp] FTP response: Client "172.28.1.101", "150 Here comes the directory listing."
Tue Apr  7 21:32:43 2015 [pid 2195] [ftp] FTP response: Client "172.28.1.101", "226 Directory send OK."
Tue Apr  7 21:32:56 2015 [pid 2195] [ftp] FTP command: Client "172.28.1.101", "TYPE I"
Tue Apr  7 21:32:56 2015 [pid 2195] [ftp] FTP response: Client "172.28.1.101", "200 Switching to Binary mode."
Tue Apr  7 21:32:56 2015 [pid 2195] [ftp] FTP command: Client "172.28.1.101", "PASV"
Tue Apr  7 21:32:56 2015 [pid 2195] [ftp] FTP response: Client "172.28.1.101", "227 Entering Passive Mode (172,28,66,17,187,148)."
Tue Apr  7 21:32:56 2015 [pid 2195] [ftp] FTP command: Client "172.28.1.101", "STOR IMG_7862.JPG"
Tue Apr  7 21:32:56 2015 [pid 2195] [ftp] FTP response: Client "172.28.1.101", "553 Could not create file."
Tue Apr  7 21:32:56 2015 [pid 2195] [ftp] FAIL UPLOAD: Client "172.28.1.101", "/IMG_7862.JPG", 0.00Kbyte/sec
```

Конфиг

```
##local config
write_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
listen=YES

##anonymous config
anonymous_enable=YES
anon_root=/opt/ftp/public
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
anon_other_write_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=YES
chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=public

pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES


##enable loging
xferlog_enable=YES
vsftpd_log_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
log_ftp_protocol=YES

##file privilege
local_umask=022
anon_umask=022
#file_open_mode=022
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте в системе:

```
useradd public
chown /opt/ftp/public public
chgrp /opt/ftp/public public
chmod 755 /opt/ftp/public
```

закоментируйте строку anon_umask=022 и
попробуйте снова загрузить файлы и покажите логи.

Comment: не помогло.

`Wed Apr  8 13:40 2015 [pid 1592] [ftp] FTP response: Client "172.28.66.153", "200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV."
Wed Apr  8 13:40 2015 [pid 1592] [ftp] FTP command: Client "172.28.66.153", "STOR 123.txt"
Wed Apr  8 13:40:06 2015 [pid 1592] [ftp] FTP response: Client "172.28.66.153", "553 Could not create file."
Wed Apr  8 13:40:06 2015 [pid 1592] [ftp] FAIL UPLOAD: Client "172.28.66.153", "/123.txt", 0.00Kbyte/sec
Wed Apr  8 13:40:13 2015 [pid 1592] [ftp] FTP command: Client "172.28.66.153", "TYPE A"
Wed Apr  8 13:40:13 2015 [pid 1592] [ftp] FTP response: Client`

Comment: Попробуйте сделать так:
    usermod -d /opt/ftp/public ftp
    chown -R ftp /opt/ftp/public
Закоментируйте следующие строки:
    anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
    anon_other_write_enable=YES
    chown_uploads=YES
    chown_username=public

Перезапустите сервис:
    service vsftpd restart

Попробуйте загрузить файл, и пришлите логи.

Comment: Нашел в инете инструкцию, для настройки с нуля vsftpd с чтением/записью для anonymous: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8129#p214503

Answer (score 1):

Что бы все заработало, права на директорию для записи должны выглядеть так:
`drwxrwxrwx 2 public ftp   4.0K Apr  8 14:56 public`

ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО группа `ftp`, при любых раскладах ничего работать не будет)

Answer (score 0):

Меня очень смущают в конфиге строки:

```
chown_username=public
```

и

```
anon_umask=022
```

Попробуйте поиграть этими параметрами, а так же поставьте для теста права на каталоги, куда производится запись - `chmod 777 /opt/ftp/public`

После этого, если на FTP зальется файл, посмотрите от какого пользователя записался файл - `ls -la /opt/ftp/public`